# gist in exclude constraint in postgres

Tags: postgresql, constraints

I created table using exclude constraint.but i do not know the use of gist in exclude constraint?Why we specify the gist keyword in exclude constraint?.Any specify reason for this.

```
CREATE TABLE Employee_age_Details(
name varchar(50),
age integer,
EXCLUDE USING gist
(age WITH <>));
```

Comment: ok.but any specify reason for using gist in exclude constraint?.is it index?

Comment: thank you.so performances also improve for this column.am i correct?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It actually does the opposite. The given EXCLUDE forces all employees to have the same age, not different.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  While GiST indexes offer the most flexibility, other ones do work with EXCLUDE.  For example, you could do `USING hash (age with =)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default index type, Btree, does not offer support for the '<>' operator.  The GiST index type (under btree_gist) does.  You must use an index type which supports the operator.

If you changed the constraint operator to '=', then you could omit the "gist".  But in that case you should just use a unique constraint, as it does the same thing better.